# How can I configure JBoss JDBC data source connections outside the XML config file?

Tags: configuration, jboss, datasource

I would like to override the portion of JBoss that loads JDBC connection information from the XML config file.  I would like to continue using the rest of JBoss's connection pooling/caching features. I just want to load the connection data from another source.

**Which MBean should I be implementing and how do I configure the override in JBoss?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JBoss -ds.xml descriptors actually cover a multitude of sins. If you look on the JBoss JVM console, you'll find 4 or 5 MBeans there for each data source. You could potentially do this programmatically, but I wouldn't give good odds on your chances.

My suggestion would be to use a 3rd-party connection pooling library (e.g. [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)). Define the pool using that, and then [bind the resulting DataSource to JNDI](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/guide/jndi-howto.html). CLient application using the pool shouldn't know any difference.

Comment: I was hoping to keep JBoss's existing pooling and just load the connection metadata from a service.  Looks like I'll need to override a lot more to have this ability.  Thanks for the response.